# Bullet z - position

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, simulation

The code im using works fine, except for the Z position.
The maximum distance is aquired at an angle of around 53 degrees, instead of the 45 it should be.
I made my own toDegree and toRadian function, because js interprets sin and cos from a Radian points of view.
Any help?

```
function Bullet(I) {
    I.zVelocity = Math.sin(toRadians(turretpitch)) * 5;
}
```

second part:

```
bullets.forEach(function (bullet) {
        bullet.zVelocity -= 0.05;
        bullet.z += bullet.zVelocity;
        if (bullet.x > bgImage.width || bullet.x < 0 ||
            bullet.y > bgImage.height || bullet.y < 0 ||
            bullet.z < 0) {
            bullet.explode();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Check what `turretpitch` is before and after you call `toRadians`.

Comment: is your cannon muzzle at `z=0`?

Comment: yes, cannon muzzle is at z 0

Comment: turretpitch is not the problem , I have its value on the screen as text, and I can controll its value myself, the problem lies in the formula